# How to create a table of random characters in XeTeX

Tags: tables, xetex, cjk

I want to create a table of 1000 characters picked randomly from the unicode block "unified CJK ideograms" (4E00-9FFF). Each cell should contain exactly one huge character, no character should appear twice.  It would be great too if one could specify a seed, so that one can create the same set of characters again.

Is there a way to create such a file automatically using (Xe)TeX? I am not very skilled in doing TeXnical programming, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can of course generate such test text with any programming language you like. It is usually easier to do it out of TeX.

Comment: @Leo Good idea either.

Comment: ... _why_!? I'd love to know what use this could be put to...

Comment: @Seamus Basically, it is a friend of mine who learns Chinese. He recently asked me, how to find out how many characters he knows. So my idea is to take a sample of 1000 characters from Unicode and let him tick everyone he knows. Then I can calculate how many characters he knows by using statistics.

Comment: @FUZxxl: As a native Chinese speaker, I think I know no more than 6000 Chinese characters, but there are more than 60000 CJK characters in Unicode charset. For a Chinese learner, the first class 3755 characters (out of 6763) from GB2312-80 charset is quite enough.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Believe me, the 3755 characters are quite enough for a learner, althouth they may not suffie a professional researcher. There are only 3600 different characters in *Hongloumeng* （in Simplified Chinese). For the smaller charset, your friend can test all of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use a simple approach to generate the list. It may cost too much memory and can be improved using better algorithm.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scale=0.8,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[nofonts]{ctex}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\parindent=0pt

\usepackage{pgfcore,pgffor}
\pgfmathsetseed{2} % set seed if you wish
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,...,1000}{%
  \loop
    \pgfmathrandominteger\randind{"4E00}{"9FA5}%
  \ifcsname used\randind\endcsname\repeat
  \expandafter\xdef\csname used\randind\endcsname{}%
  \symbol{\randind}%
  \ifnum\numexpr\i/25*25\relax=\i (\i)\par \fi
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I tested myself, I know about 40% characters in the sheet. 8000 out of 20000 is more than expected, but there're 2103 simplified Hanzi with their unsimplified variants, say I know about 6000.

Well, due to some linguistics research, the most common 3800 characters can cover 99.9% general text, and 6600 cover 99.999%. Thus, 95% characters from *Hongloumeng* do not mean quite many. The most common 3500 Hanzi's from [《现代汉语常用字表》](http://www.china-language.gov.cn/wenziguifan/shanghi/013.htm) cover 99.48% text, I think your friend can read **all of them** to make a proper test.

Comment: Note that there're some blanks in the document — some slots have no glyph in the font.

Comment: I checked [Chap. 12 of Unicode 6.0](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch12.pdf) and my fonts, it seems the range can be 4E00--9FA5, while 9FA6--9FCB may contain some rare characters.

Comment: Okay. He finally did this test and knows about 200 characters out of the list, which means about 4000 characters at all. He knows both traditional and simplified characters. I only know about 100 out of the list, so about 2000 at all.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2cm,heightrounded}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STFangsong}

\input{random}
\newcount\cjkcharcnt
%\random=3

\newif\ifshownumbers

\def\cjkchar{\setrannum{\cjkcharcnt}{"4E00}{"9FBB}%
  \ifcsname CJK\the\cjkcharcnt\endcsname
    \message{Recomputing (collision)}\let\next\cjkchar
  \else
    \expandafter\let\csname CJK\the\cjkcharcnt\endcsname\empty
    \ifshownumbers{\footnotesize(\number\cjkcharcnt) }\fi
    \ifnum\XeTeXcharglyph\cjkcharcnt=00
      \message{Recomputing (missing character)}\let\next\cjkchar
    \else
      \char\cjkcharcnt\let\next\relax
    \fi
  \fi
  \next}

\newcommand{\row}{\hbox to\hsize{%
  \cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil
  \ifshownumbers\else
    \cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil
    \cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil
  \fi
  \cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar\hfil\cjkchar}}

\begin{document}

%\shownumberstrue % uncomment to show (decimal) numbers

\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row
\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row
\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row
\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row
\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row
\ifshownumbers
  \row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row
  \row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row
  \row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row
  \row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row
  \row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row\row
\fi

\end{document}
```

Ten or twenty characters per row, fifty or a hundred rows; the (decimal) character number is attached if `\shownumberstrue` is uncommented. If by chance the same number is generated twice, it's discarded and recomputed. I get collisions very rarely (not more than one). The macros check also if the character exists in the font.

The response of `time` (without `\shownumberstrue`) is

```
real        0m2.740s
user        0m1.660s
sys         0m0.384s
```

Comment: FUZxxl needs 'no character should appear twice'.

Comment: @Leo: added the check, thanks. I've also restricted the range to `"9FBB`, as this seems the last CJK defined character.

Comment: That's good. Hmm... how about adding a `\iffontchar` test for general purpose? And I still like the `\loop \repeat` approach.